# The Grand Monarch's challenge

Tags: riddle

Later on, when Alice was still wondering about in the rabbit hole, she happened upon a grand monarch butterfly.  The butterfly mentioned to Alice that he had a wonderful treasure to share with her, but he would not give it to her lightly.  He held it up inside a small golden box.  He said, "One thing will release this treasure!"

"What is it?" said Alice.

The grand monarch butterfly smiled and said, "Ahh, to know that I will give to thee a riddle upon which is three fold.  The answer of one gives the riddle of the next!" he said, flapping his wings with glee. "And once you give me the third, we can share the treasure."

"What is it?" said Alice, as Alice's do.

> Neither of us could find the mice
>   Or the time you began to speak of
>   Lost in some whole, following what glows
>   Acting as if you discovered the mint!
>   Searching out the places where the ancient one she's
>   Taken by he who’s wings are bound
>   Finding no shoulders upon why or when
>   Ignoring all the cards, except the ace
>   Roaming around aimlessly as if
>   Seeking the answer without care for it’s worth
>   Tumbling towards aeration, most misbecoming.

Points for solving the riddle.
Bonus points for figuring out what the treasure is.

Comment: Would that be 'wandering about in'?

Comment: Are the grammar errors deliberate or accidental? Because the body of the question has the same errors too, so it is not clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not quite at the end, I think, but here's a start.  Notice that

> the first letters of each line of the riddle spell out "NO LAST FIRST".

If you interpret that to refer to

> the **last** word of each line:
>
>  mice of glows mint she's bound when ace if worth misbecoming

and the

> **first** letter of each of those words, I think NO LAST FIRST means that we should drop the first letter from each of those words.  This leaves:
>
>  ice f lows int he's ound hen ce f orth isbecoming

And that can be rearranged into

> **ice flows in the sound henceforth is becoming**

Thanks to @Sid, the answer to this is simply

> **Water**, because if ice is flowing, it is henceforth becoming...water!

Comment: Maybe, the answer to that is water.. Ice flows, henceforth is becoming water(melting into water)

Comment: @dan-russell Congrats!  You solved riddles 1 & 2

Comment: @Sid can you give a Standout answer so I can give you credit.  However, the riddle about what the treasure is remains.

Comment: @jmb.mage It would be better if Dan would edit the answer to include mine(if it is correct).. He solved the first 2 riddles.

Comment: @Sid Thanks! I was looking at it very complicatedly.  Couldn't see the forest for the trees!

Comment: Good job on finding the solution ! i think the treasure might be sugar, because a butterfly would probably enjoy sugared water, plus sugar is usually kept in a box